# What is the difference between `ts.SyntaxKind.VariableStatement` and `ts.SyntaxKind.FirstStatement`

Tags: typescript

They both share the same enum value e.g. from TypeScript 3.7.2:

```
VariableStatement = 224,
FirstStatement = 224,
```

Why are there two names for the same syntax kind?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the `SyntaxKind` enum, there are some entries which are used to denote not the concrete syntax kind, but a *class* of them. For statements, it is defined as following:

```
enum SyntaxKind {
    // snip
    FirstStatement = VariableStatement,
    LastStatement = DebuggerStatement,
    // snip
}
```

Then, to check if some syntax kind is one of the "statement" kinds, one can simply write `kind >= SyntaxKind.FirstStatement && kind <= SyntaxKind.LastStatement`. And, if the set of statement kinds will ever change, only the definition of `FirstStatement` or `LastStatement` should be changed, not these "range checks".